# Display Text from texview in multiline

Tags: android, textview

I have the below layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/decompose_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="06/07/2013"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/decompose_amount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/decompose_year"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/decompose_year"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="0000 0000 88888 88888 888888 88888 8888 888888"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decompose_sent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sent:1,200.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decompose_balance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Balance:1,200.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However the Textview  @+id/decompose_amount should ideally wrap its text and not overflow to the adjacent views. How can I achieve this multiline behaviour for that textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the some Tags From TextView

android:layout_alignBaseline

android:layout_alignBottom

android:layout_alignParentLeft

Add The ID to Linear Layout.

And add the tags

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/decompose_year"

android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linear_layout".

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to remove `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, next move the LinearLayout before decompose_amount TextView and finally set that TextView's parameters `android:layout_toRightOf` and `android:layout_toLeftOf`.

Comment: That will not work because that TextView should be to the left of the linear layout that houses two other textviews that are vertically stacked. I simply want a way to make the textviews text wrap along a specific width or something

Comment: You don't need to put views in RelativeLayout in the order you want them to be placed. You need to specify that your TextView needs to be between decompose_year TextView and LinearLayout that contains rest of TextViews.

Comment: oK...But that still doesn't answer the wrapping question

Comment: Oh, right. I forget to add `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` field  to get line wrapping. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

check the below layout may be work

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decompose_year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="06/07/2013"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/decompose_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/decompose_year"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="0000 0000 88888 88888 888888 88888 8888 888888"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/decompose_sent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sent:1,200.00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/decompose_balance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Balance:1,200.00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```